# freeing 2 pointers which have the same address

Tags: c, pointers, free

I have the following 2 code samples:

```
char *p1, *p2;
...
p1 = strdup("my str");
p2 = p1; 
...
free(p2);
p2 = NULL;
...
free(p1);
```

And the following code:

```
p1 = strdup("my str");
...
free(p1);
...
free(p1);
```

The second block, obviously, fails with double free. The question is, why the first code block exit successfully?

Comment: *The question is, why the first code block exit successfully?* How do you know it didn't corrupt some data? Just because it didn't visibly crash doesn't mean everything went well.

Comment: because the exact same code runs for years on a different platforms and on different set of inputs and never failed with 'double free' error. But obviously this code is wrong and should fail.

Comment: *never failed with 'double free' error*. Yes it did fail, just not with a message. I want to point you to your subtle error in stating "Why the first block exited succesfully". It didn't. You just didn't know about it. :-) It takes more than returning 0 without a message for a program to succeed. It must also avoid undefined behavior from start to finish.

Comment: So if it didn't put a message i can never know that something is wrong

Comment: Exactly. Running a program (aka *testing*) can only prove the presence of errors, but not their absence.

Comment: dmalloc to the rescue : debug-malloc library: dumping program, fatal error
   Error: tried to free previously freed pointer (err 61)
Aborted

Answer (score 3):

> The question is, why the first code block exit successfully ?

Both result in [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and have got the same problem. One fails while other isn't may just be coincidence. That's how UB works.

But in all probability, I'd have expected the first to fail with double-free as well.

A similar example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (void)
{
    char *p1, *p2;
    p1 = strdup("my str");
    p2 = p1;
    free(p2);
    p2 = NULL;
    free(p1);
}
```

I tried on both http://ideone.com/TwWDRr and on my Linux machine fail with double-free.

Comment: The following code does not fail : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e9733e6fd6b7c3b

Comment: @sagi your code exhibits undefined behaviour which includes "apparently working fine". Google _undefined behaviour C_.

Comment: I agree with the "undefined behavior" statement, but the problem is that on my environment I can't reproduce the issue from the first sample but with a different implementation of gcc for a different cpu arch, it always crashes with 'double free' violation. I thought that because on the second compiler it is always reproducible and with my version of the compiler it isn't. There's something I can do to catch those kind of issues. btw : valgrind did not alert about it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a double free in both code snippets. **Double free is undefined behavior**: anything can happen, including crashing or exiting successfully.

As an example, your [first snippet crashes here on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74f9dacfb5af1c19).

Comment: The following code does not fail : coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e9733e6fd6b7c3b

Answer (score 0):

So i found that in this case valgrind does not help but dmalloc comes to the rescue.

```
debug-malloc library: dumping program, fatal error
   Error: tried to free previously freed pointer (err 61)
Aborted (core dumped)
```